# Test VPN server speed without connecting to it

Tags: performance, sockets, ssl, vpn, openvpn

I have a list of VPN server credentials I could use to connect to the Internet.

I want to test each server's speed of upload/download.

One option is to make a script to connect to each VPN server and transfer a couple of files back and forth to get the average upload/download speed.

But this method is slow and time consuming(since I need to wait for the VPN client to connect to the VPN server). Is there any quicker way to test VPN servers speeds or maybe  improve my current method?

Answer (score 0):

Make Your VPN server as Iperf Server and check the vpn server speed on single and parallel connections with iperf client available on multiple platforms.

Read the Docs for more

https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/install-iperf-to-diagnose-network-speed-in-linux/

however it is recommended to take speedtest after vpn connection as Encryption and bad configuration can also degrade speed.